# How to Set TargetNullValue to Visibility.Collapsed in Binding

Tags: silverlight, xaml, binding, targetnullvalue

I'm binding `TextBlock.Visiblitiy` to something, and I want to set the `Binding.TargetNullValue` to `Collapsed`, how can I do it in XAML?

This one [How do I set TargetNullValue to a date?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/517039/how-do-i-set-targetnullvalue-to-a-date) does not work in Silverlight.  (No `x:Static`).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is working for me in SL4:

```
<TextBlock Text="Text" Visibility="{Binding Foo, TargetNullValue=Collapsed}"/>
```

Where Foo:

```
public Visibility? Foo { get; set; }
```

Comment: Hmmm, this is a workaround though it works.  As you know, Visibility.Collapsed is a constant, so there should be no instance to refer to it.

Comment: @PeterLee Well... ok. But maybe I don't fully understand your problem. Why is it just a workaround for you? Could you please update your question with some sample code, XAML to be clear what you are trying to achieve?

Comment: I tried your method before, but I misspelled the `Collapsed` .  What a mistake!  It's working.  Forget my previous comment.