# Control not being hidden when binding source is null

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I have set viewmodel as page's datacontext, and binding pivot items with an Individual collection property. However the binding is working correctly when there is data, but initially when data is not available it is not working properly, I basically want to hide the textbox below the ItemsControl but don't know whats wrong with this code.

```
<phone:PivotItem Header="Tweets" Margin="{StaticResource PivotItemMargin}" DataContext="{Binding Tweets}">
                <ScrollViewer>
                    <StackPanel>
                        <ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding Result}">
                            <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                                <DataTemplate>
                                    <Grid Margin="0,0,0,30">
                                        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                            <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
                                            <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                                        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                            <RowDefinition Height="35" />
                                            <RowDefinition Height="75" />
                                        </Grid.RowDefinitions>

                                        <Image Grid.Column="0" Grid.RowSpan="2" Source="{Binding userImage}" Margin="0,0,10,0" MaxWidth="100" MaxHeight="100" Stretch="UniformToFill" Visibility="{Binding userImage, Converter={StaticResource NullToVisibilityConverter}}" />
                                        <TextBlock Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="0" Text="{Binding name}" Foreground="{StaticResource AppForegroundHighlightTextBrush}" TextWrapping="NoWrap" TextTrimming="WordEllipsis" FontSize="{StaticResource TitleFontSize}"/>
                                        <TextBlock Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="1" Text="{Binding ShortTitle}" Foreground="{StaticResource AppForegroundSubtextBrush}" TextWrapping="Wrap" VerticalAlignment="Top" FontSize="{StaticResource SubtextFontSize}"/>
                                    </Grid>
                                </DataTemplate>
                            </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                        </ItemsControl>
                        <TextBlock DataContext="{Binding Tweet}" Grid.Row="2" Text="all Tweets" FontWeight="Bold" Visibility="{Binding hasMore,Converter={StaticResource BooleanToVisibilityConverter}}"/>
                    </StackPanel>
                </ScrollViewer>
            </phone:PivotItem>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When `DataContext` is null, binding will use value specified in `TargetNullValue` property. Therefore, try to set `TargetNullValue` property of `Visibility` binding to `Collapsed` and you [won't even need converter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21791828/binding-visibility-to-datacontext/) :

```
.......
<Image 
    .......
    Visibility="{Binding userImage, TargetNullValue=Collapsed}" 
    />
.......
```

Comment: hey, thanks. All these days I were uselessly creating NullValueToVisibilityConverter. :)

Comment: you're welcome :) but looking at your code again, it looks more like windows phone (silverlight) instead of WPF. I've only tested this in WPF though

Comment: yes its windows phone, but it worked perfectly on it as well.